# LinkedList implementation add method[C++]

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list

Hi Everyone I'm doing the LinkedList implementation with classes in c++, so far I've done only the node class and add method. But it isn't working, for example I add a new element and when I check the first pointer it is pointing to the last element I just added...

Node Class:

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
private:
    T element;
public:
    Node<T> *next;

    Node( T e ){
        element = e;
        next = NULL;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Node<T>& nd)
    {
        os << nd.element;
        return os;
    }   

};
```

And the LinkedList class:

```
 template<class T>
 class LinkedList{

    private:
        int size;

    public: 
        Node<T> *first;
        Node<T> *last;          

        LinkedList(){
            first = NULL;
            last = NULL;
            size = 0;
        }

        void add( T element ){
            Node<T> n (element);

            if( size == 0 ){
                first = &n;
            }else{
                last->next = &n;
            }
            last = &n;
            size++;     
        }

        int getSize(){
            return size;
        }


   };
```

So for example I do in the main the folliwing:

```
LinkedList<int> list;

list.add(5);
list.add(7);


cout << *list.first;
```

And it shows '7' as the first element...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One very important problem is that the node you add is a local object, i.e. it exists only inside the `add()` function. You are taking its address and trying to store it in the list, but that address will be invalid as soon `add()` returns.

Comment: So how I should add it?

Comment: The simplest direct fix would be to use `Node<T> *n = new Node<T>(element);` instead of `Node<T> n(element)`, and then `n` instead of `&n`. But you will also need to ensure that you `delete` the node objects at the time when you remove them from the list (or when you clear or destroy the list). A better solution therefore would be to declare the `next` pointers as `std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>`, create them as unique-ptr and move them into `first` and `last->next`, respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this.  By "this", I mean storing a pointer to a locally scoped `Node` instance, and expecting that object to persist outside of its original scope:

```
    void add( T element ){
        Node<T> n (element);     // This will only exist for the function's duration

        if( size == 0 ){
            first = &n;          // <-- naughty
        }else{
            last->next = &n;     // <-- naughty
        }
        last = &n;               // <-- naughty
        size++;     
    }
```

As you can see, you've been very naughty.  Once the function exits, that node is deleted.  Actually, it only existed on the stack, so it just kinda vanishes.  As luck would have it, when you call the function again, you just happen to get the same stack address back so it looks like your first node has changed.

So what do you do?  Allocate on the heap:

```
    void add( T element ){
        Node<T> *n = new Node<T>(element);

        if( size == 0 ){
            first = n;
        }else{
            last->next = n;
        }
        last = n;
        size++;     
    }
```

This is no longer naughty, and you can continue to make other pointer-related mistakes that are the basic rites of passage of a C or C++ programmer. =)

Make sure that when you are finished with your linked list, you crawl over it and `delete` each node to release the memory that you allocated.